# Finding the number of surfaces in a solid (which is formed by performing some operations on a 2d shape)

Tags: geometry, 3d, visualization

Need help understanding how x1 in the image has just 11 surfaces and not 12, i cannot visualize it :(

I cannot understand what's going on in the image, can someone please explain in easy terms (dummy alert!), i would greatly appreciate it.

Or maybe any useful links/resources could also be of great help! :)

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piGpb.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Well I'm a dummy too. To me it seems you just drag that shape along the trajectory of a letter $V$. As the original shape has 5 edges, you get 10 surfaces vertically + 2 horizontal surfaces. I count 12 as well. I do wonder what the definition of "surface" is in this context, especially if you look at the circle for the second part of the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please write full details of the question in the body (instead of referring to another source). You can even add images here. Also, the title should be more general than what you wrote. I suggest you take a look at other questions.

Comment: Probably the one that cannot 'see' the sunlight will not be counted. :-)

Comment: All surfaces have to be counted,curved or flat, visible from the front or not... I think that the transformations being performed (especially the second step of the transformation) on x are such that it can only generate 4 sides. Thus, 6(from the upper part) + 5(lower part) = 11 (total, including top and bottom). But i cannot completely understand this. 

Could that even be possible?

Comment: If the so-called "3D operations" are not specified, the number of surfaces could be anything. It could well be that the two faces on the back lie on the same plane, and thus count as a single surface.

Comment: Let $A$ be the leftmost vertex of $X$ and $\ell$ be the union of the two leftmost edges of $X_1$. It seems you can generate $X_1$ from $X$ by sliding a copy of $X$ along the $z$-direction with $A$ always lies on top of $\ell$. Based on the picture, the edge of $X$ you cannot see is parallel to the direction of horizontal part of sliding, that particular edge will trace out a single concave hexagon as face instead of two faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the unknown 3D operation is the "extrude" operation appears in various
3D CAD/modelling softwares ([AutoCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD),[SketchUp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SketchUp), ...) 
or 3D graphics libraries ([Three.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three.js), [X3DOM](https://www.x3dom.org/)).

Different softwares/libaries may use different name but the basic idea is the same. It is a way to create
a solid from a cross-section (a geometric shape lies on a plane).

Geometrically, one starts with a 2D planar shape $S$ and a continuous curve
$\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with starting point $\gamma(0)$ belongs to $S$. One then parallel translate
$S$ so that the image of $\gamma(0)$ always lies on top of $\gamma(t)$. The resulting solid is the union of the image of $S$
at different $t$. More precisely, it is the 3D solid:

$$V = \bigg\{ p + \gamma(t) - \gamma(0) : p \in S, t \in [0,1] \bigg\}$$

If $\gamma(0)$ is the origin, the solid $V$ is known among geometers as the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) 
of the point set $\gamma([0,1])$ and $S$.

For practical application, one typcially impose some extra constraint to limit what $\gamma$ could be.
One choice is require $\gamma$ to be at least piecewise $C^1$, i.e continuous differentiable up to $1^{st}$ order. Aside from finitely many $t$, the tangent vector $\gamma'(t)$ is defined, non-zero and never parallel to the plane 
holding $S$.

Consider the special case where the cross-section is a planar $n$-gon and $\gamma$ is a polyline consists of $m$ line segments.
When one increases $t$ from $0$ to $1$, each edge of $S$ will trace out $m$ quadrilaterals, one for each segment of $\gamma$. 
In the absense of any relations among directions of segments on $\gamma$ and edges on $S$, solid $V$ will have $mn + 2$ faces.

The actual number of faces of $V$ can be less than this. 
At those $t_0$ where $\gamma'(t_0)$ is discontinuous.
If the two limiting tangent vector $\gamma'(t_0\pm) \stackrel{def}{=}\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0\pm}\gamma'(t_0+\epsilon)$
is coplanar with the tangent vector of an edge $e$ of $S$. The two quadrilaterals traced out by $e$ at $t \ge t_0$ and $t \le t_0$
will share the same normal vector. This mean they will merge into a single face.
Let $N_\parallel$ be the number of this sort of events. The number of faces of $V$ is $mn + 2 - N_\parallel$.

Let's take the solid $X_1$ as an example. One can generate $X_1$ by taking the pentagon $X$ as $S$ and the union of two leftmost edges of $X_1$ as $\gamma$. Notice at the back of $X$, the tangent vector of the edge there
seems to be coplanar with the two tangent vectors on $\gamma$. This means $N_\parallel = 1$ the number of faces of $X_1$ becomes $2(2)(5) + 2 - 1 = 11$.

One can generalize this to other planar shape. In particular, those $S$ whose boundary consists of $n_c$ circular arcs and $n_\ell$ line segments. If $N_\parallel$
is the number of instances where the two limiting tangent vectors $\gamma'(t_0\pm)$ is coplanar with the tangent vector of a straight edge of $S$,
the number of faces of $V$ with be $m(n_c + n_\ell) + 2 - N_\parallel$.

Let's take the $Y$ as another example of $S$. Its boundary $\partial Y$ consists of $n_c = 2$ circular arcs and $n_\ell = 10$ line segments. $4$ of the line segment seems to be parallel to the reference direction indicated by the orange dashed line. Since $m = 2$ and there is only one discontinuity in $\gamma'(t)$,  $N_\parallel = 4$. The number of faces of corresponding 3D solid $Y_1$ should be $2(2 + 10) + 2 - 4 = 22$.

**Notes**

I first learned this operation in SketchUp but never know what it is. I finally know its name when looking up documents on x3dom.js many years later. Neither of them explain the concept well. A web search returns this [article](https://thesourcecad.com/extrude-presspull-commands/) on the extrude command in AutoCAD. It is quite readable and explain the operation clearly. Take a look if you are interested.